# How to get thr branch of a commit with nodegit

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit

I'm trying to know how I can get the branch in which a commit was created in (not the head). I know a branch is just a 'tag' attached to a commit (the head of that branch)

[image]

For example, in this image, what would I need to do to get the branch of the node **E** using [nodegit](http://www.nodegit.org/) or another git library.

I looked in the documentation, but I didn't find an equivalent to `git branch --contains`

Thanks !

Comment: What would you expect, when the feature branch cool-new-feature was merged and then deleted? The commit will still be there, but onlycontained in the master bracnh.

Comment: @milbrandt Yeah, but what if the branch wasn't deleted

Comment: `git branch --contains` doesn't tell the branch where a commit was created. It tells from which (local) branches a commit now is reachable. I took a quick look at the documenation and I think you could use apis to 1)get a branch;2)list its commits;3)test if a commit is among them;4)loop to local/remote/all branches, if there isn't an existing single api to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to:

1. Iterate over all the branches.
2. Find the ancestor of each branch's tip against the commit with `NodeGit.Merge.base(repository, branchTip, interestedCommit)`.
3. Then if the `returnedCommit === interestedCommit` then you're fine